# How can you check if a window is minimized via the terminal in linux

Tags: linux, unix, window

How can you check if a window is minimized via the terminal in linux?

Comment: Which window manager are you using?

Comment: The default windows manager for Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

```
xwininfo -name 'Window Title' | grep 'Map State:'
```

Look for `IsViewable` versus `IsUnMapped`; these come from the `map_state` field returned by [`XGetWindowAttributes`](http://www.xfree86.org/4.4.0/XGetWindowAttributes.3.html).

(At least, that works with traditional window managers; I don't know if Compiz does screwy stuff to allow for thumbnailing minimized windows.)

Comment: It won't work with Enlightenment (e17), where the `map_state` seems to be always `IsViewable` (this is a feature, which allows for instance [screen captures of hidden windows](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/93159/26952)).

Comment: Doesn't work either on Ubuntu 13.04 with Compiz. The result for some window is `Map State: IsViewable`, for others is `Map State: IsUnMapped`, but this field seems not related to the actual visibility (normal or minimized) of a window.

Answer (score 1):

```
if xwininfo -all -id $windowIdGoHere |grep "Hidden"; then
  echo "is hidden"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[ $(xwininfo -id 0x60001d -all | awk '/Maximized/{print}' | wc -l) -eq 2 ] && echo Maximized
```

where `0x60001d` is window ID. See `xwininfo -h` for other ways to identify a window for testing.